# What is the laplacian of a complex function of ONE complex variable?

Tags: complex-analysis

In the book it is stated as $\Delta f:=f_{xx}+f_{yy}$ but how can you find the 2nd order derivative in one complex variable?

Comment: You can write a complex function as $f=Re(f)+iIm(f)$.

Comment: And one complex variable $\cong$ two real variables.

Comment: I'm talking about it in relation to the complex conjugate variable

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that.

Comment: Let $\partial_x, \partial_y, \partial, \bar{\partial}$ be short-hands for $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$, $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$, $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{z}}$. We have
$$\partial_x = \partial + \bar{\partial}, \partial_y = i(\partial - \bar{\partial}) \quad\text{ and }\quad
\Delta f = (\partial_x^2 + \partial_y^2)f = 4\partial\bar{\partial}f$$
The Cauchy-Riemann condition for a complex function $f$ to be analytic is equivalent to $\bar{\partial} f = 0$